# NonJews in a MIkvah (not in the water)

Tags: halacha, gentiles, mikvah-ritual-bath

Is there any halachic reason why a nonJew should be forbidden from going into a mikvah room (not into the water) without a Jew present? (e.g., for cleaning or for other purposes)?

Comment: I go to a Chabad men's mikvah and the cleaning staff is emphatically non-Jewish...just one data point but worth adding

Comment: @Josh it could be the Bor is locked or something, so there's no concern of tampering

Comment: @DoubleAA I know of a mikvah that was under the supervision of Rabbeim from Lakewood, NJ (not Chabad supervision) that had exactly that arrangement for decades.The cleaning staff were all non-Jews and the entire Orthodox community used it without reservation.

Comment: @Double AA at this particular location the non-Jewish cleaning staff is responsible for topping off the water levels, changing the chlorine cartriges in the buoy, and running the scum-skimmer machine. They are in direct contact with the water.  The mikvah itself may or may not be kosher for kelim and women

Comment: Is there a problem with a Gentile using the mikvah, even if another Jew is in there?

Comment: @DoubleAA: Even if they have access to the Bor, or otherwise maintain the water, how could the mikvah become nonKosher?

Comment: @steve pour in a bottle of wine? We can imagine more bizarre situations too, but in principle it is definitely possible.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Do we assume that such an unlikely act could happen and therefore ban them from being there?

Comment: That is indeed your question.

Comment: See is mikvah. There are many non Jewish people in the see,

Comment: @kouty a sea cannot be hampered with vs. An actual mikvah which can be made Passul